# Elastic search 'bulk' fuzzy match

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to leverage ES fuzzy match for matching city names. For example, for these several inputs (Chicago, Chicago, IL, Chicago -IL, Chicago, USA, Chicago land, greater chicago area etc), I want to return one standard city name (Chicago,IL).

Simple fuzzy match works fine.

```
PUT /fuzzy_items/city/_mapping
{
  "city": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "simple"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I've several documents (ex. 10,000) which needs to be normalized. Other operations have bulk API.. ie. If I need to index 10,000 docs,  bulk API is handy to achieve this purpose in fewer calls.

Is there a similar feature for fuzzy match? meaning, can I send array of inputs ["chicago,USA","Minneapolis, MN"] and expect a fuzzy matched response array ["Chicago,IL","Minneapolis,MN"]?

The problem I'm trying to overcome is how 'not' to make 1000s of calls to fuzzy match and achieve the same with fewer calls.

Or

Is there a different way of achieving this, may be using [elastic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) ?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: if you trying to reduce the rtt to elasticsearch probably you could use [msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) ?